# Currency Converter with Js

Tags: javascript, html, css

So i want to create a simple currency converter using Js and i want to do it by creating to list with 5 available coins(USD,EUR,GPB,AUD and JPY) and user must select from first list the coin he want to convert and the at the second list he must select what coin currency he want as a result.Here is what i have done so far:

```js
function calculate() {
  var amount = parseFloat(document.getElementById("amount").value);
  var select = document.getElementById("select");
  var select1 = document.getElementById("select1");
  var result = document.getElementById("result");

  if (select.value === "USD") && (select1.value === "USD")  {
    result.value = (amount * 1);
  }
  if (select.value === "USD") && (select1.value === "EUR")  {
    result.value = (amount * 0.88);
  }
  if (select.value === "USD") && (select1.value === "AUD")  {
    result.value = (amount * 1.37);
  }
  if (select.value === "USD") && (select1.value === "GBP")  {
    result.value = (amount * 0.69);
  }
  if (select.value === "USD") && (select1.value === "JPY")  {
    result.value = (amount * 108.96);
  }
  if (select.value === "EUR") && (select1.value === "EUR")  {
    result.value = (amount * 1);
  }
  if (select.value === "EUR") && (select1.value === "USD")  {
    result.value = (amount * 1.13);
  }
  if (select.value === "EUR") && (select1.value === "AUD")  {
    result.value = (amount * 1.55);
  }
  if (select.value === "EUR") && (select1.value === "GBP")  {
    result.value = (amount * 0.79);
  }
  if (select.value === "EUR") && (select1.value === "JPY")  {
    result.value = (amount * 123.47);
  }
  if (select.value === "EUR") && (select1.value === "EUR")  {
    result.value = (amount * 1);
  }
  if (select.value === "EUR") && (select1.value === "USD")  {
    result.value = (amount * 1.13);
  }
  if (select.value === "EUR") && (select1.value === "AUD")  {
    result.value = (amount * 1.55);
  }
  if (select.value === "EUR") && (select1.value === "GBP")  {
    result.value = (amount * 0.79);
  }
  if (select.value === "EUR") && (select1.value === "JPY")  {
    result.value = (amount * 123.47);
  }
  if (select.value === "GPB") && (select1.value === "EUR")  {
    result.value = (amount * 1.27);
  }
  if (select.value === "GPB") && (select1.value === "USD")  {
    result.value = (amount * 1.44);
  }
  if (select.value === "GPB") && (select1.value === "AUD")  {
    result.value = (amount * 1.98);
  }
  if (select.value === "GPB") && (select1.value === "GBP")  {
    result.value = (amount * 1);
  }
  if (select.value === "GPB") && (select1.value === "JPY")  {
    result.value = (amount * 157.08);
  }
  if (select.value === "AUD") && (select1.value === "EUR")  {
    result.value = (amount * 0.64);
  }
  if (select.value === "AUD") && (select1.value === "USD")  {
    result.value = (amount * 0.73);
  }
  if (select.value === "AUD") && (select1.value === "AUD")  {
    result.value = (amount * 1);
  }
  if (select.value === "AUD") && (select1.value === "GBP")  {
    result.value = (amount * 0.51);
  }
  if (select.value === "AUD") && (select1.value === "JPY")  {
    result.value = (amount * 79.51);
  }
  if (select.value === "JPY") && (select1.value === "EUR")  {
    result.value = (amount * 0.0081);
  }
  if (select.value === "JPY") && (select1.value === "USD")  {
    result.value = (amount * 0.0092);
  }
  if (select.value === "JPY") && (select1.value === "AUD")  {
    result.value = (amount * 0.013);
  }
  if (select.value === "JPY") && (select1.value === "GBP")  {
    result.value = (amount * 0.0064);
  }
  if (select.value === "JPY") && (select1.value === "JPY")  {
    result.value = (amount * 1);
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Convert US Dollars to Euros </h1>
<form>
  <p>
    <label for="amount">Amount:</label>
    <input type="text" id="amount" value="">
    <select id="select">
      <option value="USD">USD </option>
      <option value="EUR">EUR </option>
      <option value="GPB">GBP </option>
      <option value="AUD">AUD </option>
      <option value="JPY">JPY </option>
    </select>
    <select id="select1">
      <option value="USD">USD </option>
      <option value="EUR">EUR </option>
      <option value="GPB">GBP </option>
      <option value="AUD">AUD </option>
      <option value="JPY">JPY </option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" id="result" value="">
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="calculate();">
    <input type="reset" value="Reset">
  </p>
</form>
```

But so far it doesn't work at all... And i cannot understand why... What have i done wrong?

Comment: What about it doesn't work? Do you see any errors in your console?

Comment: When i press the "Calculate" button nothing happens...

Comment: You need to check your console (hit F12 on Windows or Opt + Cmd + I on Mac). You'll be able to see what's wrong by reading those errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the brackets but your `if`statements should be an `if else if` because one a match is found you don't need to check the other rates.

```
if (select.value === "USD" && select1.value === "USD")  {
    result.value = (amount * 1);
} else if (select.value === "USD" && select1.value === "EUR")  {
    result.value = (amount * 0.88);
}
```

An even better approach would be to create an object of all the rates and check the rate exists using a single `if` statement.

```
var rates = {
    USD : {
        USD: 1,
        EUR: 0.88,
        AUD: 1.37,
    },
    EUR : {
        EUR : 1,
        USD : 1.13,
        AUD : 1.55,
    }
}

if(rates[select.value] && rates[select.value][select1.value]){
    result.value = amount * rates[select.value][select1.value];
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The `if` statements should not be closed between `&&` signs. So where you have

```
if (select.value === "EUR") && (select1.value === "EUR")
```

it should be

```
if (select.value === "EUR" && select1.value === "EUR")
```

Comment: @AggelosSfakianos I am so glad to have helped you on your way.